# Cryptic crash in iOS app applicationWillTerminate method

Tags: ios

Getting a lot of crashes from crash reporting in an iOS app with the following stack trace. I've not been able to reproduce this. My questions are:

Is this happening when the app terminates and therefore I shouldn't worry too much about it?

If not how can I figure out where this is coming from if I can't reproduce it locally?

```
0    libobjc.A.dylib     (anonymous namespace)::AutoreleasePoolPage::pop(void*) + 313
1    libobjc.A.dylib     objc_object::sidetable_release(bool) + 94
2    CoreFoundation  _CFAutoreleasePoolPop + 16
3    Foundation  -[NSAutoreleasePool release] + 120
4    SmartRoam  
MyAppDelegate.m line 95
-[MyAppDelegate applicationWillTerminate:]
5    UIKit   -[UIApplication _terminateWithStatus:] + 152
6    UIKit   -[UIApplication _handleApplicationSuspend:eventInfo:] + 2474
7    UIKit   -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 774
8    UIKit   -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 72
9    UIKit   _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 664
10   GraphicsServices    _PurpleEventCallback + 608
11   GraphicsServices    PurpleEventCallback + 34
12   CoreFoundation  __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 34
13   CoreFoundation  __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 346
14   CoreFoundation  __CFRunLoopRun + 1406
15   CoreFoundation  CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 524
16   CoreFoundation  CFRunLoopRunInMode + 106
17   GraphicsServices    GSEventRunModal + 138
18   UIKit   UIApplicationMain + 1136
19   SmartRoam  
main.m line 41
main
```

1. Is this happening when the app terminates and therefore I shouldn't worry too much about it?
2. How can I figure out where this is coming from if I can't reproduce it locally and it never touches my application code.

Comment: Which iOS version are you deploying?, by default they were suspended, did you modified the specific key in the info.plist to make the app close? applicationWillTerminate is called only for apps that don't support background

Comment: Seeing it only on iOS4 and iOS5 and only with iPhone 3gs, iPhone 4 and iPhone 4s. Not sure what that tells me. I have not set UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend in info.plist.

Comment: I guess it will eventually go away as users migrate to newer iOS versions. Still bothersome as it's by far the biggest source of crashes in our app.

Comment: Found something on the doc:`For applications that support background execution, this method is generally not called when the user quits the application because the application simply moves to the background in that case. However, this method may be called in situations where the application is running in the background (not suspended) and the system needs to terminate it for some reason.` So is your app running on background (that means that you had registered for background functionalities)?

Comment: Yes, it always happens when the app is in the background.

Comment: Which service is your app using in background mode?